# replace character from file in matched strings lines only

Tags: regex, unix, sed, scripting

I am trying to replace "$" char from file in a single line where particular strings matched .
In my case I am having a file like below

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK;

SET DEFINE OFF

DECLARE 
g_GITvision varchar2(100) := '$Testversion: 1234 $';
sql code
sql code
```

I want to remove "$" from only line which matched with starting of "g_GITvision".
tried so far

```
sed -e 's/\(\^g_GITvision\)\$/\\' file
```

Any help would be apriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed '/^g_GITvision/s/\$//g' file > newfile
```

Here,

- `/^g_GITvision/` - finds a line starting with `g_GITvision`
- `s/\$//g` - replaces all `$` chars on that line.

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/tgRbvX):

```sh
s='WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK;
 
SET DEFINE OFF
 
DECLARE
g_GITvision varchar2(100) := '"'"'$Testversion: 1234 $'"'"';
sql code
sql code'
sed '/^g_GITvision/s/\$//g'  <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```sh
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK;

SET DEFINE OFF

DECLARE
g_GITvision varchar2(100) := 'Testversion: 1234 ';
sql code
sql code
```